# Android Studio: Invalid maximum heap size: -XmxheapSize, Error:Could not create the Java Virtual Mchine

Tags: android-studio

I have recently upgraded my RAM from 2GB to 4GB, I tried to re-install Android studio in my machine through the Ubuntu shell and an this error in the below image:

[image]

Is there anyone ever encounter this error before? If there is any useful resource, please share with me to solve this issue.

Comment: Sorry the image ain't loaded but the error is: Invalid maximum heap size: -XmxheapSize

Comment: I have helped you to edit and allow the image to be show, do Accept my edit request so that others will able to understand your error through the picture clearly.

Comment: By the way how do I get to Accept the edit request @Eric Wong

Comment: You already did accept, the picture is showing now.

Comment: To Accept Edit, you just simple go to the Notification and you will saw you Edit Request, click in and click accept. As simple as that. Usually people would help you edit your post to make it clearer and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue too after I haphazardly edited my VM options from within Android Studio without really paying attention to what I was copy-pasting off StackOverflow. In my case the error was this:

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4096m # <------ increase this to most of your RAM
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

My machine has 8GB of RAM, so this helpful error message is instructing me to set this to a higher value.

In your case, `-XmxheapSize` is clearly not a valid value.

On Ubuntu I had to edit the offending line in this file:

```
~/.AndroidStudio3.1/config/studio64.vmoptions
```

(folder and filename may be different for you depending on which version of Android Studio you have and whether you're using 64 or 32bit.)

Run `ls -a` in your home folder to see all hidden folders, if you're not sure what your Android Studio config folder is named. See [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html) for more details.